# expected np.ndarray (got DataFrame)

Tags: python, pytorch

I wanted to find out the output_size of a convolution operation, but I am strugglin with converting my dataframe into a tensor.

```py
output_size = torch.nn.Conv2d(3, 5, 5,stride=1, padding=3,    
                dilation=1, groups=1, bias=True, padding_mode='zeros')

fashion = torch.from_numpy(load_fashion)
input_ = torch.Tensor((fashion.values), dtype=torch.float)  


output = output_size(input_)
```

Comment: Assuming `load_fashion` is your dataframe, `fashion = torch.from_numpy(load_fashion.values, dtype=torch.float)` oughtta be enough. Note that you also need to reshape your tensor into (batch_size, channel, H, W) shape before passing to Conv2d.

Answer (score 1):

I can't completely understand your problem as your code is not formatted properly in your question but the error is just an expected datatype error.

You need to convert your dataframe to a np array. Just add .values at the end of your dataframe. So if your input was a sample dataframe like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col1":[1,2,3,4], "Col2":[2,2,3,4]})
```

Convert the whole thing to a numpy array like so:

```
sample_array = df.values
```

or convert one column to a np array like so:

```
sample_array_2 = df["Col1"].values
```

**Update:**
As mentioned in the comments, pandas recommends `.to_numpy()` instead, so use something like:

```
sample_array = df.to_numpy()
```

Comment: The [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) recommends using `dataframe.to_numpy()` instead.

Comment: Ah yes, you're correct. Updating my answer.